# Why Material UI buttons not working correctly on onClick events?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

When working with material-ui buttons, clicking the text inside button triggers click event but not shows the id of button. It only shows id when I click the corners of the button.

```
 <Button
        id="2"
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        className={classes.button}
        startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
        onClick={(event) => console.log(event.target.id)}
      >
        Delete
 </Button>
```

I have tried to add a z-index on the button but it didn't work

Example code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-meninsky-1met8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: try this `onClick={(event) => console.log(event.currentTarget.id)}`

Comment: Using ```event.currentTarget``` instead of the ```event.target``` solved. Thank you.